# pdf-tools indirect buffers

Tags: pdf, docview, pdf-tools, indirect-buffers

I am using an indirect buffer of a pdf from a `pdf-tools` `PDFView` buffer. This works except the indirect buffer is in `DocView` mode, and therefore I can't use any of the `pdf-tools` features in that buffer.

Is there a way to clone the `PDFView` buffer into another `PDFView` buffer?

Answer (score 3):

Indirect buffer need special support, since their buffer-file-name is
nil.  But this is currently not implemented in pdf-tools.  So it seems
that the answer is no.

Comment: FYI: when setting the `buffer-file-name` to the original file name, the indirect buffer comes up in `pdf-view-mode`.  It correctly lists the number of pages in the original document.  However, it only shows whatever page was last open in the original document.